# Eclipse tomcat project context menu option

Tags: eclipse

I recently upgrade to Eclipse Kepler and I loose the context menu option Tomcat project to create war file to deploy an application.

What can I do?

Comment: You lost the context menu ? Or did you lose the Server project ? Or you can't deploy your war?

Comment: Using "Tomcat project" option in context menu from a project I could create war file to deploy. I have installed a Tomcat plugin (the same i had in Eclipse Indigo) but this option doesn't appear.

Comment: Can you share the name and the link of the tomcat plugin ?

Comment: I used Eclipse Marketplace to install the plugin. Its name is UqbarTomcat XT Edclipse Plug-in 2.0.0.

Comment: The link is: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/uqbar-tomcat-xt-eclipse-plug?mpc=true&mpc_state=

Answer (score 0):

I am not that much familiar with this plugin.

But can you verify your installation from its official [page link](http://uqbar-tomcat-xt.sourceforge.net/download.html) .

Its mentioned that you need to add a couple of other dependencies manually. Like `DevLoader.jar` and the `Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin`

**Edit**

If you just want to deploy the project to your tomcat, you can use the *Run as* option as well. Just right click on the project, select *Run as* and then *Run on Server*

And to make a war, you can simply export as war from the export option (Right click on project -> export 
)

Comment: I haven't the option Export > Web > war. I don't understant anything!

Comment: The option should be there. Did you update your eclipse to kepler or you performed a fresh installation ?

Comment: I did a new installation indeed.

Comment: And the option is not there.

Comment: The options are: General, Install, Java, Plug-in Development, Run/Debug, Tasks, Team.

Comment: My best guess that you are using **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** while you require **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**